# How to read/write a generic class with upickle

Tags: scala, upickle

Say I have the following trait:

```
trait T {
    val x: Int
}

def foo(i: Int): T
```

I would like to bet able to write and read this trait using upickle without knowing what the specific class is. e.g.:

```
upickle.default.write(foo(3))
```

Such that I could elsewhere define foo to be something like:

```
case class A(x: Int)

def foo(i: Int): T = A(i)
```

I am thinking I need to define an implicit Writer as a member of T but I don't know what the appropriate syntax would be?

Answer (score 0):

```
trait T {
  val x: Int
}
object T {
  implicit val rw: ReaderWriter[T] = ...
}
```

The problem is what to put into the `...` part: if you have a `T` value, you can just store its `x`:

```
... = readwriter[Int].bimap[T](
  t => t.x,
  i => new T { val x = i }
)
```

The problem with this solution is that reading a written `A(3)` won't return an `A`. And this isn't really solvable without making `T` sealed or otherwise handling a specific set of subclasses only.

You could include a class name as well when writing, but that won't help if the class has any fields other than `x` to store:

```
class B(override val x: Int, y: String) extends T
```

If `T` *is* `sealed`, you just write

```
... = macroRW
```